How the change the horizontal space before the beamercolorbox?
The title frame element's frametiles isn't align to the left...
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \nointerlineskip
    \hskip-\beamer@leftmargin %
    \leavevmode
    \hbox{
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1.02\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex]{frametitle}
            \insertframetitle \enspace \small \insertframesubtitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        }
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is a title}
\framesubtitle{This is a subtitle}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is a title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}


\hskip-\beamer@leftmargin or just \hskip-5pt like are not behave as good as I think, how to set the proper distance? where to know the parammeters?



Please keep your questions focused on one problem per question.

Sorry for that.

The missing % signs at the end of your lines will add spaces. What you see in your example is the missing % after \hbox{. Once you remove the extra space, your beamercolorbox will be perfectly aligned with the edge of the frame:
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \nointerlineskip
%    \hskip-\beamer@leftmargin %
    \leavevmode
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex]{frametitle}
            \insertframetitle \enspace \small \insertframesubtitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }%
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is a title}
\framesubtitle{This is a subtitle}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is a title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Oooooooops???! the comment %, I will re-edit my question and make it focues on just one point, thanks!
